# Remote Server returned an error : Not Found

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wrote one program which sends request for particular site and gets response. It properly runs with localhost.  but, if i put www.google.com then it prompts error as "The remore sever returned an error: Not Found"

*****Code**************

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsPhoneApplication2
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(@"http://www.google.com"));

            request.BeginGetResponse(r =>
            {
                var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState; 
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(r);
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { textBox1.Text = response; }));
                }
            }, request); 

        }


    }
}
```

---

please tell me soultion 
thanx in advance

Comment: Does it work in the IE within emulator? try to check via NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() whether the connection is available at all

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me.

Can you access Google from IE on the device/emulator?
I suspect that this is a networking issue local to you and not related to the device.